# How to add padding to image added by button

Tags: javascript, html

Here i have got a button named generate cat which generates images but i want the images to have padding.

> JS

```
         function generateCat(){
            var image=document.createElement("img");
            var fluidcontainer=document.getElementById("roma");
           image.src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
        
           fluidcontainer.appendChild(image);
}
```

> HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="fluid-container">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Cat Generator</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="cat-gen-btn" onclick="generateCat()">Generate
                Cat</button>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="roma"></div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <script src="index.js" async defer></script>

</body>

</html>
```

> CSS

```
.fluid-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

if the image is directly added from Html then we can add an attribute and then give it padding but how to add padding when we generate the image by javascript?
Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Just go through the complete code that I have provided. If you need to know about any step, just let me know :) Do vote and accept the answer if you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DOM to change CSS styles. All you have to do is add `image.style.padding = "enter padding in px";`. Put this code before you append the image. You can use the DOM to change the css styles of any property. Just add element.style.csspropertyhere = "value";

Answer (score 1):

You need to set padding on the parent div of img in Javascript and then add the image. Here is the full code:)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const catBtn = document.querySelector("#cat-gen-btn");

  catBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
const image = document.createElement("img");
const romaDiv = document.getElementById("roma");
romaDiv.style.padding = "2rem";

image.src =
  "https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg";

image.style.width = "100%";
image.style.height = "auto";

romaDiv.appendChild(image);
  });
});
```

```css
.fluid-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fluid-container">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Cat Generator</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="cat-gen-btn">
          Generate Cat
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" id="roma"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```